# Gnuplot pm3d not plotting all data

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
0 0 1
0 1 -1

1 0 -1
1 1 1
```

I'm plotting this `with pm3d` with the number of colours in the palette set to two. What I'm expecting is four squares, two white and two black, in opposite corners. However, when I plot this, I just get one black square measuring 1 by 1. I was initially working with much larger grids, and gnuplot seemed always to be plotting one less row and column than I wanted. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pm3d` option is averaging your z value between the points that you have defined, this is standard and I am not sure it can be changed without formatting your data. What you can do is to unset the `pm3d` option and plot with the `with image` style. I actually find this preferable because the figures produced are of much smaller size (byte-wise speaking).

With your set of data:

```
plot "data" with image
```

Yields what you want:
[image]