# Gnuplot heatmap from matrix

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'm trying to plot a heatmap from a matrix. So far, my code looks like this:

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'output.pdf'
set autoscale yfix
set autoscale xfix
set palette defined (0 0 0 0.5, 1 0 0 1, 2 0 0.5 1, 3 0 1 1, 4 0.5 1 0.5, 5 1 1 0, 6 1 0.5 0, 7 1 0 0, 8 0.5 0 0)
set pm3d map
splot 'topologyDataActive' matrix notitle
```

With this data:

```
100.0 43.48 49.39 0.52 22.26 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
43.48 100.0 92.35 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
49.39 92.35 100.0 68.0 91.13 40.35 49.57 98.96 81.57 8.87 22.96 37.91 46.09 1.04 0.0 
0.52 0.0 68.0 100.0 86.26 39.48 0.0 1.04 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
22.26 0.0 91.13 86.26 100.0 95.3 41.57 23.65 12.52 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 40.35 39.48 95.3 100.0 82.26 95.13 58.43 29.57 66.78 67.83 2.43 22.61 0.0 
0.0 0.0 49.57 0.0 41.57 82.26 100.0 95.48 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 98.96 1.04 23.65 95.13 95.48 100.0 82.43 18.61 10.78 0.0 8.35 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 81.57 0.0 12.52 58.43 0.0 82.43 100.0 80.52 80.87 11.3 82.96 24.52 1.04 
0.0 0.0 8.87 0.0 0.0 29.57 0.0 18.61 80.52 100.0 85.91 96.35 97.39 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 22.96 0.0 0.0 66.78 0.0 10.78 80.87 85.91 100.0 85.91 85.91 85.91 0.52 
0.0 0.0 37.91 0.0 0.0 67.83 0.0 0.0 11.3 96.35 85.91 100.0 97.22 99.83 0.17 
0.0 0.0 46.09 0.0 0.0 2.43 0.0 8.35 82.96 97.39 85.91 97.22 100.0 99.3 1.04 
0.0 0.0 1.04 0.0 0.0 22.61 0.0 0.0 24.52 0.0 85.91 99.83 99.3 100.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.04 0.0 0.52 0.17 1.04 0.0 100.0
```

Which gives me this graph:
[image]

So far that looks quite ok. But first of all, one column and one row is missing and I'm not sure why. Also, I tested it with less data, only this:

```
100.0 43.48 
43.48 100.0
```

This gives me only one square:
[image]

If I add a column and a row of zeroes, I get four squares, but the colours are off:
[image]

The question now is, how do I get the correct colours and the correct lines of columns and rows?

Comment: [Gnuplot pm3d not plotting all data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22790143/2604213)

Comment: Same as the comment on the answer below. I get transitions between squares, which I do not want.

Comment: No, you don't get any transitions. That is a problem with some pdf viewers. Try e.g. Firefox to view the pdf and you'll see, that you get a perfect image.

Comment: What the heck... You are right. I didn't expect that.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25736904/2604213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to extend your `splot` command with `with image`:

```
splot 'topologyDataActive' matrix with image notitle
```

The image plotting style projects a uniformly sampled grid of data values.

Comment: I tried that before, but then I get transitions which I definitely do not want. Each square needs to have one colour and there should be no transitions between colours.

Comment: Try the normal `plot` command if you do not need surface or 3D. This produces also heatmaps without transition or interpolation.

Comment: For the sake of completion: with image solves it, but check the Pdf viewer if there is transition.