# heatmap color not relating with data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I am trying to create one heatmap using Gnuplot and my data file structure is looked like below:

```
6 5 4 3 1 0

3 2 2 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 2 3

0 0 1 2 4 3
```

the cell values are z values and columns represent y-axis and row are x-axes. that means the first value 6 is the z value where the y-axis is 5th position at x label zero. However, while plotting the heat map I am getting a different color which does not correlate with the z value. Also, I am getting five bins for the x-axis (which is supposed to be 6)and 4 bins (which is supposed to be 5) for the y-axis. My simple code is written below:

```
set pm3d map
splot 'm.txt' matrix
```

Please help me out of this confused situation.

Thanks.

Comment: pm3d interpolates your data, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791385/2604213

Comment: Do you really have blank lines between each row of data values? If you remove those, you can use `plot 'm.txt' matrix with image`.

Comment: plot 'm.txt' matrix with image works fine for me. However, the bin sizes are not even. How can I fix that thing?

Comment: Try `set size ratio -1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine for me.

Comment: I want another help. It is related to the same heatmap. This time, I want to show the cbtics. I know it can be done by: set cbtics. However, I want to set the minimum tic value to 0 (0 value is absent to the files from where it takes the values) and maximum value based on the highest value taken from the file. And the tic will show only for the minimum and maximum value. Is that possible to gnuplot? Thanks in advance.